boto3 upload_file: how to specify Checksum?
I'm using boto3's upload_file to upload files to some S3 buckets.
This works well:
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
s3_client.upload_file(
    Bucket="my_bucket",
    Filename="local_filename",
    Key="remote_filename"
)

Now I want S3 to validates my uploaded file checksum (let's say sha256) at upload time. boto3 documentation mention the ChecksumAlgorithm parameter for this. But how this supposed to be used ? I can't find more details in boto3's documentation nor
If I try to specify only ChecksumAlgorithm, it fails:
s3_client.upload_file(
    Bucket="my_bucket",
    Filename="local_filename",
    Key="remote_filename",
    ExtraArgs={
        "ChecksumAlgorithm": "SHA256",
    },
)

Fails with:

botocore.exceptions.SSLError: SSL validation failed for https://s3.my-cloud-provider.net/my_bucket/remote_filename EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:2427)

I'm a bit confuse that here I don't have to provide any locally-computed sha256.
Am I missing something ? Or is this checksum validation available only when using S3.MultipartUploadPart.upload ?
